# Browse through answers with "next page" and "previous page"

Tags: php, pagination

This is the code below! It echos out all answers for a specific question in my forum. I want about 6 answers shown on each page. Hence if there are 12 answers on one specific question then it should show the first six from the start then if the user clicks "next page" it should show the user the next 6 answers. I don't know how to fix this step in my progress. Any help is more than appreciated! Thanks.

```
    <?php

    $tbl_name2="forum_answers"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
    $result2=mysqli_query($con, $sql2)or die(mysqli_error($con));
   while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>

<table id="answers" width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td id="answerid">#<?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" >
<tr>


<?php

INCLUDE 'dbh.php';
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM forum_answers LEFT JOIN users ON forum_answers.a_name = users.username WHERE forum_answers.a_id=".$rows['a_id']." AND forum_answers.question_id=".$rows['question_id']);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            if ($row ['image'] == "") {

                echo "<img src='bilder/default.jpg'";
                ?><td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><a href="viewanswerprofiles.php"> <?php echo $rows['a_name']; ?></a></td><?php
            } 
            else { 
                echo "<img src='bilder/".$row ['image']."'";
                ?> <td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><a href="viewanswerprofiles.php"> <?php echo $rows['a_name']; ?></a></td><?php

            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
        ?>
<td id="datetimeanswer" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="answertext" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Answer:</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_answer']; ?>
        <button id="removeanswer" name="remove">Remove</button>
        <button id="removeanswer">Edit</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The word you're looking for on Google is `pagination`. Basically, your next/previous page links would include a page number, which you then use to determine an offset for in your query (e.g. `LIMIT 0,6` for the first 6, `LIMIT 6,6` for answers 6-12)

Comment: try to watch a tutorial about pagination you have to pass variable when you click next page increase to 2 then you have to do 2*6 which is 12 so you need result from 6 to 12 by using clauses in your SQL where ID=12 and order by ID desc limit 6 and so one with other pages.